# How to Create a "Base" Test Method in Junit or TestNG

Tags: junit, testng

Given the following:

```
class TestCase {
    @Test
    public void test(){
        assertTrue(true);
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to create a base test method? I have some repetitive code that needs to happen for each test. Or perhaps I am just as well-off writing a utility method and calling it each time in the beginning of each test?

It can't be in a @beforeMethod because I need the info in the test itself.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just put it in a base class and extend that class (at least for TestNG).